# A depth-ﬁrst search of an undirected graph produces the same number of tree edges

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I'm trying to show that a depth-ﬁrst search of an **undirected** graph always produces the same number of tree edges. I know that this statement does not hold for direct graphs.

What I did: Lets assume that there are two different DFS runs on the same undirected graph G (with n vertices) so the number of tree edges in first run is x and the number of tree edges in second run is y.

Now I want to say that if each DFS run gives us one DFS tree then we know that x=n-1=y which means that our assumption is incorrect. The problem is that each DFS run can return some a few trees and not exactly one so I need to "count" the number of tree edges in each tree.

I also tried to prove the theorem with induction but didn't get any results. Any ideas on how to show it? I also tried to find a full proof online but it looks like it's not an interesting theorem to prove. The only thing I came across with is the counterexample for the direct case.

Disclaimer: I posted this question at SO at first but moved it here because it feel more right to ask it here. Let me know if it's not the right place to ask it.

Tree Edge is an edge which is present in the tree obtained after applying DFS on the graph.

Comment: In general, the number of edges will be n-r where r is the number of connected components.

Answer (score 0):

if You're original graph is not connected, then your statement is wrong and DFS may produce different "Tree edge counts" on each connected group in your graph unless you want to combine all the spanning Trees together.

but if your original graph is connected it's simple , because of your graph has n nodes. then your Tree also has n nodes and each tree with n nodes has n-1 edges. so
x=y=n-1

Comment: Why must it be connected? The sum all tree edge in all of the DFS trees should be the same in each DFS run, no matter where you start.